# Python read from text file

Tags: python, file-io

I want my simple python program to go to a text file and collect 5 lines to print out.

I have got this far but it returns the whole file which I don't want to do yet.

```
file=open('IH.txt','r')
text = file.read()
print(text)
file.close()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you open a file using `return` and increment the counter variable by one. In case the counter reaches 5 do return.

Comment: go through `https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files`

Comment: Vidya, I'm a complete novice and don't know what 'return' is

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
file=open('IH.txt','r')
text=""
for i in range(6):
    text += file.readLine()
print(text)
file.close()
```

`read()` reads the entire file. `readline()` reads only a line.

The loop has 5 iterations and in each iteration, the next line from the file is appended to `text` via concatenation.

You might also want to do exception handling.

Comment: for i in range(6):
        text += file.readline    #this works, thank you

Comment: Actually, that is repeating in each iteration like you say, I just want it to print 5 lines in one go then stop, I later want to print the next 5 lines and stop again.  Any idea?

Comment: @UKcodeNovice What do you want to do after reading the lines? Would it be okay to make the lines as a list?

Comment: I want to ask a question about the lines

Comment: @UKcodeNovice Have a look at [islice from itertools package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). But even that is a form of loop it seems.